# Docker uvicorn bind port

Tags: python, docker, uvicorn

I'm doing a little experiment and I don't understand why I am having this error.
I'm running an easy web server on a python base image and the final CMD is:

```
CMD ["uvicorn","myapp:app","--port","8080", "--reload"]
```

using fastapi

I'm trying to bind the port to my host IP.
If I run the container with this image it works but I'm not able to reach the server with the browser in the host. (docker CLI: `docker run -it --name t1 --rm -p 8080:8080 image_name`) ---> in my host browser http://localhost:8080/ doesn't work (the fastapi I'm sure endpoint is OK)

I think because by default it is bind on my container IP; In fact if I try curl on localhost:8080 from my container it works properly

```
CMD ["uvicorn","myapp:app","--port","8080", "--reload"]
```

However I tried to "map" the --host flag with the localhost IP (view from the container), that is `172.17.0.1` but this time it doesn't work the deploy the container because I get this error:

```
CMD ["uvicorn","myapp:app","--host","172.17.0.1","--port","8080", "--reload"]
```

```
---> ERROR:[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I know it works if I set the `--host to 0.0.0.0` but I'd love to bind the container port just to the host IP.

Do you know how? And could you explain me why doesn't it work?

Comment: Provide more details of your environment. Is it docker in WSL. Is it vanilla linux? which Distro, etc. Also versions and steps taken.

Comment: yes you are right. I'm running directly on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: about steps, they are the common ones: 1. build of the image, 2. run of the container, 3. check the server on chrome host browser

Comment: The solution IS to set the host to 0.0.0.0, that is the way for your container to accept connections from the outside (that is, your PC). Why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: 0.0.0.0, just to be clear - enables _all_ incoming connections from *all* network interfaces. If you don't have a firewall you should know that anybody can access the server in your current subnet and all subnets that has access to it (normally, the internet).

Comment: Yes you both are right but for this test i'd like to bind the port just to my host machine. I'd like to be able to access the server only from my host browser, not from all interfaces. i though I could do it setting the --host to 172.17.0.1 (which is the host IP from the container view) in the uvicorn command. However it doesn't work

Comment: I though that binding a port means this. For istance, if i bind my port 80 on 127.0.0.1 the only IP able to access that port will be the one specified (127.0.0.1 ---> my localhost --> in this scenario my backend container). But what if I want to bind my port 80 of the container to my host (172.17.0.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container runs in a modified network environment.  You generally must set the container process to bind to 0.0.0.0; in your example, `uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080`.

You can see this by launching a temporary container

```
$ docker run --rm busybox ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

The *container* has two Docker-internal IP addresses.  The loopback address is fixed, but the other one is not; it will depend on which Docker network you're using, how many other containers are running, and other details.

However, since your program is running inside this environment, it must bind to one of these addresses or the other, or (`0.0.0.0`) to all of them.  172.17.0.1 is frequently the gateway address of the default bridge network, but not a container address *per se* and you won't be able to bind to that.  If one of your host's addresses is 10.20.30.40, again, that's not one of the container's addresses and you can't bind to it either.

The flip side of the restricted network environment is that the container port also isn't accessible from outside Docker without publishing a port.  (There is an exception that you can directly call a container IP address from a native Linux host that's not using Docker Desktop, but only from the same host; it isn't a recommended approach though.)  You *must* use a `docker run -p` option to publish the port.  You can select a specific host interface to bind to there if you want, or remap it to a different port.

So in summary:

1. If you want to make calls into the container from anywhere else, the process in the container usually must bind to 0.0.0.0; it's hard to know another address that will work.
2. If you want to make calls from outside of Docker, including host tools like browsers and from other hosts, you need a corresponding `docker run -p` option.